# Access the attributes of the caller element in the options section of the jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I have some links that according to what they will show when clicked they have different width and height data (this links are generated in server side) like:

```
<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-1" data-width="80%" data-height="80%">content 1</a>
<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-2" data-width="50%" data-height="80%">content 2</a>
```

Now I want to use something like:

```
$('.inline').colorbox({inline:true, width:$(this).data('width'), height:$(this).data('height')});
```

but `$(this).data('width')` does not seem to be valid in the options section

Comment: Just use `data-cbox-` prefix for your attributes, look my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Colorbox can be passed a function to be evaluated in place of a static
>   value for any of its properties.

```
$('.inline').colorbox({
     inline: true, 
     width: function(){ return $(this).data('width'); }, 
     height: function(){ return $(this).data('height'); }
});
```

Comment: very nice, I there any way to access attribute in options for any plugin?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani, it may depend on a certain plugin implementation. This topics may help: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-access-this-inside-my-custom-jquery-widget-callback, https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.inline').each(function(){
     $(this).colorbox({inline:true, width:$(this).data('width'), height:$(this).data('height')});
});
```

Comment: Thanks Titus (+1). This will solve my current problem, but I am really curious to know if I can access the caller from options.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would be using `data-cbox-` prefix for data attributes:

```
<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-1" data-cbox-width="80%" data-cbox-height="80%">content 1</a>
<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-2" data-cbox-width="50%" data-cbox-height="80%">content 2</a>
```

All attributes that start with `data-cbox-` will be automagically added to options.

---

**Demo**

```js
$('.inline').colorbox({inline: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-1" data-cbox-width="80%" data-cbox-height="80%">content 1</a>
<a class="inline" href="#inline-content-2" data-cbox-width="50%" data-cbox-height="80%">content 2</a>
```